# Blank activity not getting created using New->Android Activity Wizard

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

I had recently updated my Android SDK from 22.3 to 22.6. After updating, I tried creating a **Blank Activity** using the wizard. I am unable to create one as I used to create earlier. Also, I am unable to create LoginActivity, or Settings Activity etc.

I somehow managed to create the Activity through wizard, I found that instead of extending simple **Activity**,  my class was extending something else.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278479/eclipse-doesnt-generate-mainactivity-java-activity-main-xml

Comment: I've answered to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289164/adt-blank-activity-created-with-fragment-activity

The answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22684192/389324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the update link today

[check here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)

Comment: Such answers must be posted as comments rather than an individual answer

Comment: @pk4393 agreed. but that was a long time back. It's good that you spent your valuable time digging into my profile :-P

Answer (score 1):

I have not suffer this problem with 22.6 but with 23. In my case, the problem seems to be the free maker sintax of the .flt files of the template.

Just in case this could be useful to others, I've solved this issue changing two files:

`$ANDROID_SDK/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity/recipe.xml.ftl` original:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipe>
    <#if appCompat><dependency mavenUrl="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+"/></#if>
    ...
```

I've added `?has_content` after `<#if appCompat` in line 4:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipe>
    <#if appCompat?has_content><dependency mavenUrl="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+"/></#if>
    ...
```

The other file is `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity/root/res/menu/main.xml.ftl`. The original version starts with:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"<#if appCompat>
...
```

I've added the same string at the end:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"<#if appCompat?has_content>
...
```

The same errors exist in many other activities templates...

Keep in mind that these changes will be overwriten with the next SDK update... I hope Google solve this issue, because developping for Android with Eclipse is becoming a headache.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue for me. It seems that SDK is broken again.

Answer (score 0):

I also have that issue, seems a bug in new SDK tools

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, so I updated the Android to 1.5 and after the SDK version.
It works for me.

Android Studio 1.5 link:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-rc-1