# Can't create activity on eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

This is the third time I delete from SDK Manager, I want it use Android 1.6 but I got as the picture below.

After clicking "Next", "Next" and "Next", I got this and I can't create it.

Just in case, here is the SDK Manager:

[Please see picture](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2wdu98n.jpg).

Comment: I think it is a bug & u r getting this error after installing/ updating SDK manager tools.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278479/eclipse-doesnt-generate-mainactivity-java-activity-main-xml & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278621/blank-activity-not-getting-created-using-new-android-activity-wizard ,,,, Both asked today

Answer (score 0):

The error in the 2nd screen shot telling you that, the template required minimum SDK 7 but you select in the first screen when you entered the project name SDK 4. Change it to SDK 7.

Comment: I installed Android 2.1, the same thing "Minimum Required SDK: API7: Android 2.1 (Eclair)", "Target SDK: API4: Android 1.6 (Donut)", "Compile With:Google APIs (Google Int.) (API7)" and "Theme:None" it gives me an error and "Minimum Required SDK: API4: Android 1.6 (Donut)", "Target SDK: API7: Android 2.1 (Eclair)", "Compile With:Google APIs (Google Int.) (API4)" and "Theme:None" it dosnt give an error at the beginning but I can create activity

Comment: Beside that, Im getting this error in the "Console" [Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK: Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-19': build.prop is missing.

Comment: You set Minimum Required SDK: API7 then you made Target SDK: API4. You can not make that because the target SDK should be API7 which is your minimum requirement or higher.

Comment: Ok, Im still getting the same error.. but what should I put in the "Minimum Required SDK", "Target SDK", "Compile With" and "Theme:None" in these, in the SDK Manager, I installed Android 1.6 and Android 2.1 plus all the "Tools" and "Extras" .. I want to work with "Android 1.6" please :)

Comment: I think you need also API 8 (Android 2.2) for compiler so install in from the manager then from the wizard for your project select the following:
Min Required SDK: API 8
Targer SDK: API 8
Compile with API 8
Theme None

After that, you can change the min required SDK from the file AndroidManifest.xml by changine the values inside this tag <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: It didnt work! It also said "This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8" I installed API14 and it works (maybe), the AndroidManifest.xml in the root I changed it to what you wrote me (just 18 to 8) it was <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> and it became <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />, the "src' and "res/layout" got nothing!!!!

Comment: What did you means with got nothing? what is your expectation and what happened?

Comment: I mean it should have src>Package Name>main.java, the res>layout>Main.xml

Comment: Did you create them before and they removed when you changed the minimum sdk? anyway, you can add the activity and the layout since the activity is normal java class extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: I dont know why was it removed, I removed everything and reinstalled them again, I couldnt find them!

Comment: I set New Android Project again but when I reached the Create Activity, it told me "This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8" I removed the checked Create Activity and it worked incompletely, you said I can create them, I couldnt with the src and the layout, the xml tells me its rendering target (Android 4.0) tho, I set it to API8, all of it!!

Comment: You are not forced to create it from the wizard. You can create normal java class and make it extends Activity. You need more knowledge to be able to make this. Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html