# Eclipse creates fragment layout automatically, how can i disable it

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I dont want to use fragments and fragment layout. Is this possible to disable eclipse's that property? Firstly, i create a class and xml files then i declare them in Android Manifest file this works for me but it takes a long time if i can disable it, it will be easier.

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/KgMJvQ.png]

Comment: Start making a project with empty Android template?

Comment: I've already made a project with empty Android template. After i updated my eclipse, it creates fragment layout automatically.

Comment: I've edited my question, there are screenshots, where is my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT blank activity created with fragment activity..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289164/adt-blank-activity-created-with-fragment-activity)

Comment: download previous version here: http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/8648344/Android_SDK_r22.0.1_Full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android heard our voice :).

Just upgrade or [download](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download) ADT version to 23.0.2 or higher.

Now you can choose blank activity like this,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While creating  new Application,
just copy the Layout Name to the Fragment Layout Name(eg:activity_main)

Voila!
You get an activity without the fragment part.

remove this part of the code from activity

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
```

Clean the project.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse provides a facility to create a Simple Android Application which does not contains any `Fragment` classes or Layout files.

You can just create simple project besides selecting any kind of templates for the project.

Comment: I've edited my question, there are screenshots, where is my mistake?

Comment: Which ADT you are having ? I guess now the latest ADT have kept the functionality of adding the layout of fragments into the default structure also. That is why its showing options to add the fragment layout name. Whereas it doesnot show in my eclipse.

Comment: I've the latest version (ADT 22.6)

Comment: That is why its showing option for the fragment layout name setting.

Comment: But i don't want to create fragment so how can i do?

Comment: If you do not want to create a fragment then you can simply that classes from your structure.

Comment: I know i can do that but i don't want to do this every time. I think it mustn't be mandatory.

Comment: Yes i know it must not be mandatory but if its added into latest ADT then it will always come by default. As i can see in your SS it has made compulsory to add the name of fragment class also.

Comment: Also i don't know why did he/she vote down my question. If you have any idea you DO NOT do anything. Whatever, thank you for your ideas @GrlsHu

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Blank Activity project` with *Navigation type* as **none** and other entries as default.

Copy the contents of `fragment_main.xml` into `activity_main.xml` and delete the `fragment _main.xml`

Now go to `MainAcitvity.java` remove only this portion from `MainActivity` `onCreate()` method:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
   }
```

finally remove class `PlaceholderFragment{}` and its contents from `MainActivity.java` 
and then run your application.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no setting to accomplish what you want at the moment (I agree there should be one). As a workaround, this answer to a similar question shows how to remove fragments from the newly created project.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482259/1287459

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this. 
[ADT blank activity created with fragment activity..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289164/adt-blank-activity-created-with-fragment-activity/22684192#22684192)

It works fine for me, when it comes to creating blank activities, without fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I done it by replacing the BlankActivity(22.6.2) folder to the older sdk BlankActivity(22.6.1) present in the tools/templates directory in android-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Empty Activity instead of creating Blank Activity if you don't find the Empty Activity option, you have chosen a newer version of the software instead of the updated version software.

Answer (score -1):

You just put the same name that your "Layout Name" in "Fragment Layout Name" and the wizard will not create the fragment file

Answer (score -1):

When you are creating a new Android Application Project using the wizard, after you get to the screen that asks you to select type of activity, **choose Empty Activity instead of Blank Activity,** which is the default.

No fragments will be created.