# Fragment Layout Name

Tags: android, layout, fragment, adt

I have been using Android ADT for a few weeks now and i used to normally create new activities by going to:File>New>Other>Android>Android_Activity>Blank_Activity.  However after updating my 'Android SDK Tools' & 'Android SDK Platform Tools' today , its now showing a new option when I'm trying to create an activity.

When I select new blank activity and click next , its then showing a new form that i have to fill in which is titled as 'Fragment Layout Name'. Why has this suddenly appeared and does anyone know why I'm being forced to create a fragment layout as i don't want to even use this. I also remember one of my friends saying that he updated his SDK about a week ago and he stated that he had the same problem. Shall i just remove the fragment in the XML document once its loaded or is there a way to disable this so i wont have to go through this every-time.

Comment: i assume you're refering to the ADT plugin in Eclipse and have upadted the question accordingly. If you are actually using something else, please edit it with the correct context.

Answer (score 3):

The templates of files produced by "**New ...**" wizard have changed lately. Now you are **enforced** to create a new Activity with a Fragment placeholder attached. Guess that's the way the developers enforce people to build UI based on Fragments :)

There are a few workarounds for your problem:

1) Just delete **fragment layout** in your resources; delete the placeholder fragment in your Activity code and all the relevant code (FragmentManager etc); change **activity layout** from FrameLayout to anything you like.

2) Follow the recipe proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694256/1900071)

3) Don't. Ever. Use. Wizards. It is much better to create a new class and write **extends Activity** (or Fragment, Service, etc), **than** to create a template and waste your precious time changing it to your needs. And it helps to understand the lifecycle of components, too.

Comment: Always at your service, Sir! :)