# Android/Eclipse: How to create a new project without appcompat_v7

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Everytime I create an android project in eclipse it starts with an error "no resources found that matches the given name: attr xxx", in addition to a appcompat_v7 added as a project.

I found a way to resolve this issue in my current app by totally removing the ActionBar, avoiding using less than API 11, modifying all XML files and removing the created appcompat_v7 project. This solution, however, is tedious and must be done everytime I need to create, even, a simple a project.

My question is not "what is appcompat_v7", my question is how to create project without having this error everytime ?

Comment: In Eclipse, if you skip the new-activity wizard (and its portion of the new-project wizard), I think that you don't get `appcompat-v7`. On Android Studio, even that trick does not help.

Comment: possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438700/how-to-create-a-new-android-project-without-using-support-libraries

Comment: @ShrikantHavale: It is not a duplicate as it answer what is appcompat_v7 and why it is included. On the other hand, I am asking how to start my actual development instead of spending my time fixing eclipse and linking libraries (three days so far) .. Thank you anyway for pointing me to that answer, it explain the problem very good.

Comment: @CommonsWare: you are right, I can do that and I am doing it right now, but I don't want to do it any more because I used to create apps with one activity without the added library of appcompat_v7 .. what happens ? i don't know and I dont like it .. my apps are very simple:no ActionBar or ViewPager or Fragment ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want to create a project without `appcompat_v7`?. It gives you compatibility for API's under 11, so your app will work in old devices...

If anyway you want to create a project without it, in Eclipse:

Create a new `Android Application Project` and **uncheck** `Create activity` in step two (Configure project).

Comment: I used to create apps that have one activity without appcompat_v7 library added. Creating an Activity by myself is not a problem, but why do I have to do it in the first place, don't you think it is a time waster. Exactly like when fixing the error with appcompat_v7 library (and it is never fixed) .. I want to skip this simple step without too much complexity since my app does not include ActionBar, ViewPager or Fragments ..

Comment: I want to create an android app that works for 4.x.x. Will using appcompat library work for this version of Android?