# Creating an Android app using tutorial does not show a fragment layout field

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am a newbie. I am trying to learn android. I am using android tutorials to build first app. I Go to `New>Android Application Project`.

Then I insert application name as "My First App". Then a few Next,Next, using default values. On the create activity window, I select the Blank activity and click next.

Now the problem arises. On the next screen it shows only three fields:

1) Activity name

2) Layout name

3) Navigation type

The problem is that it does not show the 'Fragment layout name' field.[image: Here is a screenshot of what happens Vs. What I want to happen]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289164/adt-blank-activity-created-with-fragment-activity see this link

Comment: So this means that it is a new features added in latest ADT?? Currently I have Build: v22.2.1-833290

Answer (score 1):

You should select your maximum API version as the max you have, may be ANdroid 4.4 and minimum to be say Android 2.2. This is work for you, I think so.