# Problems with Activity Class creating in Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, android-activity

I've been studying a little of Android using Eclipse, and suddenly when i create a new Android Project is does not appear the MainActivity class.

First it was not creating the activiy_main.xml and fragment_main.xml. I tried updating in Help->Install new software and selecting Developer Tools, but it seems i have no update to do because a message "The operation cannot be completed" because i already have installed the programs.

Then i tried this solution: [Blank activity not getting created using New->Android Activity Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278621/blank-activity-not-getting-created-using-new-android-activity-wizard) that helped to create activities but not to create classes; so when i create the Android Project it not create any .java class for the activity created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the check box `Create Activity` checked on like the 4th page of creating a New Android Application and have a `Blank Activity` selected?

Comment: Yes, Create Activity is checked and i selected Blank Activity with Fragment