# ADT does not product source files when I create a new android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So when I create my project using Android ADT (v22.3.0-887826) I target android 4.3 and have everything set to default. The src folder is completely empty. From my understanding from the lynda tutorial I am following, it should generate a general MainActivity.java. I triple checked and made sure when I was creating the project, that Create Activity was checked.

I have also tried to create a new Activity (New -> Other -> Android -> Android Activity) and it generates nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse doesn't generate MainActivity.java & activity\_main.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278479/eclipse-doesnt-generate-mainactivity-java-activity-main-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the adt basically I followed this steps: [How can I update my ADT in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse)
and after that when you create a new project you will see a new MainActivity.java and the layout automatically created also added this activity in the manifest.
First step: go to Help and click on Install New Software

[image: part 1]

Second step: Click on add button, Name: add a name, Location: add this url https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and click ok
[image: part 2]

Third step:select both options, click on next, wait until instalation is complete.
after that restart the adt and create a new project.
[image]