# New Android Application wont create an activity eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I select "New Android Application" and put in

```
- Minimum Required SDK:"API4: Android 1.6 (Donut)"
- Target SDK:"API4: Android 1.6 (Donut)"
- Complex With:"API4: Android 1.6 (Donut)"
- Theme:"None"
```

Then Next >> Next >> Next, it says in the "Create Activity", "This template requires a minimum SDK version of at least 7, the current min version is 4" so I installed the "**Android 2.1 (Eclair)**" because it said SDK version 7.

I go back again and I type:

```
- Minimum Required SDK:"API4: Android 1.6 (Donut)"
- Target SDK:"API7:Android 2.1 (Eclair)"
- Complex With:"Google ApIs (Google Inc.) (API7)"
- Theme:"None"
```

Then Next >> Next >> Next, I get the same msg!

I go back again and I put stuff and I got " This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8" and many others but no use!

The question is, how can I make an application with some maps using Android 1.6?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278479/eclipse-doesnt-generate-mainactivity-java-activity-main-xml

Comment: you don't need the template. just create the application and add the activity manually.

Comment: I guess you made a recent update to the SDK?

Comment: Atish Agrawal, its not working! Vyger, it keeps telling me that there is an error in http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler